# Angularjs service

Tags: angularjs, angular-services

can anyone explain how to create a service in angular by factory method using simple example.I found some some example in some sites but i couldn't understand why there are 2 return statements and where there are returning the value and also in some examples there is only one return statement.please explain in step by step.

```
app.factory("squareService",function(){
        return{
                square:function(n){
                    var a=n*n;
                    return a;
                }
        };          

});
```

Comment: angularjs developer guide for services: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services

Answer (score 0):

@scokmen is right , you have to read the doc but You can try something like

```
angular.module('MyApp')
        .factory('serviceName',[
            function () {
                return function () {
                    sayHello: function(){
                       return 'hello';
                     }
                };
             }]);
```

And then

```
angular.module('MyApp')
    .controller('controllerName',['serviceName'
        function (serviceName) {
             $scope.hello = serviceName.sayHello();
         }]);
```

The 1st return is for the service and the other for your function. From the first you get all the service functions from the second the function result